# res.render not able to render the view

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a login function.

```
function login(req, res, next){
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            callback(null, req.body);
        },
        getAdmin,
        getHash,
        authenticate
    ],function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            res.status(406).json({ err : err});
        }
        else {
           req.session.admin = data;
            res.redirect('/userPage');
        }
    })
}
```

the `res.redirect('/userPage');` is then held here:

```
router.get('/userPage', function(req, res, next){
    console.log("its getting here");
    res.render('users/userHome');
});
```

This router is working in case when I have hyperlink from my html such as:

```
<li><strong><a href="/userPage">Users</a></strong></li>
```

But it is not working if I redirect the control from my back-end itself.

Comment: Not working how? Do you get the 406 or does it not redirect??

Comment: router.get('/userPage', function(req, res, next){
    console.log("its getting here");
    res.render('users/userHome');
});   here  I can see the console.log but then res.render does not render, and if I put <a href="/userPage"> in my html just to check then it works.

Comment: If you can see the console.log in the route, the redirect most certainly works, it's the rendering that doesn't

Comment: any way i can forcefully render my view or something

Comment: If you try to render something else, like just `res.send('I can see this')` does that work

Comment: yes its sending the string to the browser

Comment: Then the issue is `res.render('users/userHome');`, either what is rendering it, or the url, has issues, or it's expecting data from the client that isn't there.

Comment: @sacDahal Do you have any other code running after the else? Can you add return before the redirect and the render? Something like that:
`return res.redirect('/userPage');` and:
`return res.render('users/userHome');`

Comment: I just deleted everything from my function and except res.redirect('/userHome') , still the view does not render